# Distance Between Turtles (car)

Tags: distance, netlogo, traffic

Recently I've been working on netlogo especially at Traffic Basic.
I want to modify the code and make a function to calculate distance between every turtle (car) with the one ahead of them.
How can I do this?

Comment: The Traffic Basic library model only looks at the patch one patch ahead to identify whether there is a car ahead. Are you wanting to measure the distance to that car? Or are you wanting something a bit more flexible, looking as far ahead as necessary to find the car and then to measure the distance to that car?

Comment: put it simple like this, if there are 4 cars (A, B, C,D), i want to calculate distance between A and B, B and C, C and D; with assumption that D is the leading car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a `to-report` will do what you want. If you add this procedure to Traffic Basic:

```
to-report distance-car-ahead 
  ; If there are any cars within 10 patches of me
  ifelse any? other turtles in-cone 10 1 [
    ; Report the distance to the nearest one
    report distance ( min-one-of ( other turtles in-cone 10 1 ) [distance myself] )
  ] [
    ; Otherwise, report that I am in the lead
    report "I am the lead car"
  ]
end
```

Now as an example, you can modify `go` to check that this is working, like so:

```
to go
  ;; if there is a car right ahead of you, match its speed then slow down
  ask turtles [
    let car-ahead one-of turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    ifelse car-ahead != nobody
      [ slow-down-car car-ahead ]
      [ speed-up-car ] ;; otherwise, speed up
    ;; don't slow down below speed minimum or speed up beyond speed limit
    if speed < speed-min [ set speed speed-min ]
    if speed > speed-limit [ set speed speed-limit ]
    fd speed
    show distance-car-ahead
  ]
  tick
end
```

I recommend turning the number of cars down to 3 or 4 to evaluate the print statements to make sure it's doing what you expect.